# How to launch a word file in its default MSword executable from python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using windows OS and python version 3.7.1. I would like to launch a word file in its default MSword executable using python.

Please don't treat this as duplicate question because I have tried solutions given in few earlier questions similar to these. However, I could not get the desired result.

My code:

```
import subprocess
path = 'C:/Users/pavan m sunder/tutorials/Kivy/py/docx/populated_doc.docx'
subprocess.call(['open', path])
```

> I also tried using os.system() imported from os module, even that didnt work. Please. help

My error message:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: did you try this ? import os;
file = "C:\\foo\\bar\\file.docx" ;
os.startfile(file);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below program worked for me :

```
>>> import os
>>> os.startfile("C:\\Users\\foo\\bar\\Visit_Report_Dec_19.docx")
```

Your error message can be due to the fact that there is no specified file in the given path!

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The following code should do the work (it did for me):

```
import os
os.startfile('C:/Users/pavan m sunder/tutorials/Kivy/py/docx/populated_doc.docx')
```