# Opening files in python3 for windows10

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I cannot open files in python 3 actually I have a problem with the path. I don't know how to write the path for it.:/ For example I have a file(bazi.py) in folder(w8) in driver(F). How should i write it's path. Please help me im an amateur:/

Comment: check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/59404389/5658788

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, there are a couple additional ways of referencing a file. That is because natively, Windows file path employs the backslash "" instead of the slash. Python allows using both in a Windows system, but there are a couple of pitfalls to watch out for. To sum them up:

Python lets you use OS-X/Linux style slashes "/" even in Windows. Therefore, you can refer to the file as 'C:/Users/narae/Desktop/alice.txt'. RECOMMENDED.

If using backslash, because it is a special character in Python, you must remember to escape every instance: 'C:\Users\narae\Desktop\alice.txt'

Alternatively, you can prefix the entire file name string with the rawstring marker "r": r'C:\Users\narae\Desktop\alice.txt'. That way, everything in the string is interpreted as a literal character, and you don't have to escape every backslash.

File Name Shortcuts and CWD (Current Working Directory)

So, using the full directory path and file name always works; you should be using this method. However, you might have seen files called by their name only, e.g., 'alice.txt' in Python. How is it done?

The concept of Current Working Directory (CWD) is crucial here. You can think of it as the folder your Python is operating inside at the moment. So far we have been using the absolute path, which begins from the topmost directory. But if your file reference does not start from the top (e.g., 'alice.txt', 'ling1330/alice.txt'), Python assumes that it starts in the CWD (a "relative path").

Answer (score 0):

using the os.path.abspath function will translate the path to a version appropriate for the operating system.

```
os.path.abspath(r'F:\w8\bazi.py')
```